# What is the error in this code?

Tags: python, debugging, stdout

For some reason this code prints out nothing?
can someone help?

```
n = raw_input()
for i in range (10):
    if len(str(i ** 2)) == n:
        print i**2
```

Comment: Integers and strings can never be equal.

Comment: `n = int(raw_input()) `

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` does not return `int`. (Python 2) always returns strings.

Convert the result to integer explicitly with `int()`

**Demo:**

```
try:
    n = int(raw_input())
    for i in range (10):
       if len(str(i ** 2)) == n:
         print i**2
except ValueError:
    # value error
```